# Accessing a Basic HTTP authenticated file programatically in PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, authentication

I have a file in php server that is under HTTP basic authentication (i.e), the browser will ask the user for username/password when the url is hit. But I want to access the file programatically from a angular front end. I'm getting a CORS error whenever I try.

My angular code:

var headers = {};

```
         var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '....',
            headers: headers
        };
        req.params = {
            username: 'username',
            password : 'password@123'
        };

        $http(req).then(function(response) {
            console.dir(response);
        }, function(error) {
            console.dir(error);
        });
```

My .htaccess file:

```
AuthName "New Employee Mobile Application"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap-star
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off

<Files rest.php>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, Authorization“
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Files>
```

I've also tried setting an Authorization header with username:password as base64 encoded. But it still doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you restarted your web server ?

Comment: no, but didint' see that mentioned anywhere is it that i should restart the web server?